# replace text with stars

Tags: input, replace, passwords

Good day,

I just do basic, very basic HTML, CSS coding and couldn't get through my newest task - hope to get the answer here.

I want to have an input field where when I paste an e-mail address like somethingnice@gmail.com that will convert it to so*****@gmail.com and put it in an paragraph. Basically it should keep the first two letters, then put 5 stars (like in a password) and than keep what follows after @. If it's too difficult to do 5 stars no matter of the lengh of the e-mail address, I would be more then happy if it would just replace the characters beetwen the first two letters and @ with stars.

Regards,
Sonny

Comment: You need Javascript/jQuery for this - usually, altering the DOM requires JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var email = "alice@example.com";
var firstTwo = email.substring(0,2);
var domain = email.substring(email.indexOf("@"));
var sanitizedEmail = firstTwo + "*****" + domain; 
console.log(sanitizedEmail);
```

Checkout the following links:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Comment: **TimJ**, you are the greatest!
Here is the whole HTML code, if anybody needs: https://jsfiddle.net/vz7qs4m1/